# getting the uniqueness from extracted grep results BUT with stream as an input

Tags: command-line, grep, streaming, pipe

On finished input (like a file) we can do that:

```
cat file | grep -o memory=[3-9] | sort -u
```

But `sort` won't work with a stream:

```
tail -f server.log | grep -o memory=[3-9] | sort -u
```

`server.log` can be an infinite stream (a real time log). Above command can last hours.

how can I aggregate results adding another tool into the pipe,
or making somehow that `sort` will work?

OR:

what is the alternative, instead of `grep`, to have grepping there but also passing the argument into next step - next tool of the pipe.
I am not sure if pipe will allow that, at all.

maybe the second part of pipe must be a combined one (like something doing grep+sort at once)

I am only interested with the command-line approach to that.

It could be something like `watch`, but updating the previous result.

On example:
Instead of seeing a plenty of lines like:

```
memory=4
memory=4
memory=4
memory=4
memory=2
...
```

I want to see just:

```
memory=4
memory=2
```

The above output is simplified, I wanted to highlight the aggregation of such output is my main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the working solution is:

```
$ tail -f infinite_server.log | grep -o memory=[3-9] > output &
```

then

```
$ watch "cat output | sort -u"
```